# Recursion with multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I have array like this:

```
$array = [
    'Category 1',
    'Category 2',
    [
        [
            'SubCategory 1',
            'SubCategory 2'
        ],
        [
            'SubCategory 3',
            'SubCategory 4',
            [
                [
                    'SubSubCategory 1',
                    'SubSubCategory 2'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'SubCategory 4',
            'SubCategory 5',
            [
                [
                    'SubSubCategory 3',
                    'SubSubCategory 4'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

And i try do recursion:

```
function recursive($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            recursive($val);
        }
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

It throws an notice *"Notice: Array to string conversion"* because

```
   [2] => array(
        [0] => array(..)
        [1] => array(..)
        ..
    );
```

And also echo Array

In this case, when the array has such a layout. How can I avoid that notice?

Comment: it would help if you could tell us the purpose of your recursive function and your desired output.

Comment: `'category 2' => array(`...this is not true in your code above. "Category 2" in your array is a simple string at index 1 of the array. Then index 2 is an array, separately. Are you trying to create an associative array?

Comment: I corrected, thanks

Answer (score 6):

You only want to `echo` the value if it is not an array, so just add an `else`.

```
function recursive($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            recursive($val);
        } else {
            echo $val;
        }
    }
}
```